# How to know if a postgres function executed without error or failed

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

My objective is to display a message on the blade if a postgres function is successfuly executed or if the function failed.

```
public function archiver(Request $request) {

    $archivage = DB::select('SELECT archivage()');

    if(???) {
        // successful
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', "L'archivage a bien été effectué");
    }

    // failed
    return redirect()->back()->with('messageDanger', "Un problème a été rencontré lors de l'archivage");
}
```

Can I use a `try/catch`?

Thank's for help!

Comment: It wont throw an exception, so if your expecting something returned `if (!empty($archivage)) {` would suffice.

Comment: use `empty()` works even if my postgres function return nothing?

Comment: Then check `!empty` as the logic suggests.

Comment: If `archivage()` always returns empty then fix it to return somthing :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone change function behavior don't help me aha. I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try/catch` with and catch `QueryException`:

```
try {
  // your function here 
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
 // it's better if you don't use return here and log the error instead like this
  logger()->error($e->getMessage());
  // in this way you can find the log in your storage/logs/laravel.log file
}
```

Comment: thank's for your answer. But use `logger()->error($e->getMessage());` will show an error right? It's is not very good for the user ergonomy or I'm wrong?

Comment: it won't show the error to the user but i will store it in the log

Comment: I see! However, how can I display a message at the user to inform him that something is wrong if I'm not using `return  ...` ?

Comment: You can used them both if you want , this is more helpful in loop 
u can add logger first then return the error message to the user

Comment: Oh ok, so I will used both! Thank's a lot!